# Fresh installation of WordPress on CentOS produces critical error during installation

Tags: installation

[image]

Error as shown in snip.

Have tried turning on all debugging options.

Have disabled SELINUX.

Have tried chmod -R 777 .

DB creds to MYSQL work fine in cli.

No discernable errors in any Apache logs.

Has anyone seen this behavior? Have any good directions on best way to trouble shoot.

FYI: Apache works fine when pointed to an info.php file with phpinfo ()

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks,
T

PS: server is CentOS  8.1

Thanks,
T

Comment: This is all on a private local server on Hyper-V for dev purposes only.

Comment: first of all check file permission and file ownership. In order to work perfectly apache:apache usergroup should own all files of wordpress installation. Also try enabling debug log.

Comment: Does www-data own all of the wordpress install files?

Comment: yes, well, apache does.

Comment: 4 drwxrwxrwx.  5 apache apache  4096 Jun 17 15:02 .

Lol..apache owns everything. This is internal that I deactivate when not in use so I am not worried about it being hardened.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. And I feel like an idiot. I think for whatever reason; setup is pointing to old php 7.2..Trying to install 7.4 now to see if it fixes it.

Comment: don't drink and #...lol :P I think I forgot to update this machine after installing it last night. Sorry...

Comment: No worries. Please feel free to answer your own question so that when someone else has this happen they can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for wasting anyone's time. The issue was the machine was a fresh installation and running an old version of PHP FMP...

Once upgraded everything is working great.

Thanks,
T